# Is there ever a reason to create a non-clustered index on a column that is already the clustered primary key?

Tags: sql-server, index, t-sql, primary-key, nonclustered-index

Suppose that I have a table. Its primary key is clustered and consists of exactly one column. Is there ever a reason to *also* make a non-clustered index on that same column with no other columns in any part of the non-clustered index?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not under most circumstances, no. Now,if I sit here and speculate, I could see a situation where because you only have a nonclustered index, the optimizer might choose to do scans against that instead of the clustered index because it's smaller. But the query would have to be only against that one column.

Unless, we change things. Let's say it's a filtered nonclustered index. That might be useful to add to a column depending on the queries in question.

Comment: "_because you only have a nonclustered index_" - But you don't. The premise of the question is to have **both** the clustered and non-clustered indexes. I'll edit to make that more clear.